# Is there any way to enable disable YEAR from date picker in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

Is there any way to enable and disable year from date picker in android [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Exactly which datePicker R u using add code with question .

Comment: There are many [date picker libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=created). See if one offers your desired feature.

Comment: Yes, the date picker that allows to select date of birth with or without year. @cutiko